# How to show progressbar and Cancel file downloading to dropbox server in Drop-In Saver

Tags: dropbox-api

I have implemented Dropbox Saver API for uploading file to dropbox server after user logged in. Things are working good but I have some queries listed below.

1. I need to show progress bar how much file's part has been downloaded to dropbox server. How can I show it ?
2. I need Cancel functionality i.e if user want to cancel file uploading then how I can achieve it.
3. How large file size uploading can be done using Saver API ?

Comment: Most of your problems can be solved by writing code.

Comment: can you give me some sample code, on how to check file upload progress.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203835115-How-to-show-progressbar-and-Cancel-file-downloading-to-dropbox-server-in-Saver ]